# Upload image to server using C#/.NET and storing filename in DB

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, image, upload

I'm currently using the following snippet to insert data into a table in my database. It works great. But, I want to start adding filename data and not sure how to proceed.

I have the following:

```
// Create command 
comm = new SqlCommand(
  "INSERT INTO Entries (Title, Description) " +
  "VALUES (@Title, @Description)", conn);

// Add command parameters
comm.Parameters.Add("@Description", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text);
comm.Parameters["@Description"].Value = descriptionTextBox.Text;
comm.Parameters.Add("@Title", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
comm.Parameters["@Title"].Value = titleTextBox.Text;
```

I also have a *File Upload* option. But, I don't know how to use this to do the following:

- move the file to my *images* directory and
- store the *filename* value in my table.

I have added the correct **enctype** to my form but now a little lost.

Can someone explain the best way to do this?

Many thanks for any help with this.

Comment: If you are using sql server 2008 , you can consider using FILESTREAM .http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the file in an images folder, it should be:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
```

and then add the command parameters in the fileName

```
comm.Parameters["@FileName"].Value = FileUpload1.FileName;
```

Note: you must have the `FileName` field in your DB table.

Comment: Brilliant!!! This looks good to me. I'm not near the code right now but will be later today. I will let you know how I get on. Many thanks :D

Comment: What happens when you try to upload another file with the same file name? :) Should rather store original file name in DB but use something like a random guid or content hash for storing it on server filesystem.

Comment: yes, it would be better if you store original file name in the DB and store it file system with GUID.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying this just now but unfortunately get the error `"CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputFile' does not contain a definition for 'SaveAs' and no extension method 'SaveAs' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputFile' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` Any ideas?

Comment: My Form is: `<form runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and has `<input id="filUpload" type="file" name="filUpload" runat="server">`. My codebehind file includes: `filUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filUpload.FileName));` and `comm.Parameters["@FileName"].Value = filUpload.FileName;`  -- Hope this is useful. Many thanks.

Comment: If you are using HTML file upload control, then it should be like...File1.PostedFile.SaveAs and if you are using asp.net file upload control <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /> then in FileUpload1.SaveAs

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! WOO-HOOOO. Muhammad. You are a legend. High five from Scotland :D Thanks so much.

Comment: Final wee issue I'm having.... using: `comm.Parameters["@FileName"].Value = filUpload.FileName;` gives me the error `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@FileName' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.` -- Any ideas how to fix this? Many thanks once more.

Comment: You need to update your insert query and have to add parameter in your insert query...new SqlCommand(
  "INSERT INTO Entries (Title, Description,FileName) " +
  "VALUES (@Title, @Description,@FileName)", conn);

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me :) My new INSERT query is `comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO news (title, body, date_added, img1sml) VALUES (@Title, @Description, @DatePosted, @img1sml)", conn);` Currently I'm adding data like this: `comm.Parameters.Add("@DatePosted", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date); comm.Parameters["@DatePosted"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();/*error on the img1sml Add line*/comm.Parameters.Add["@img1sml"].Value = filUpload.FileName;comm.Parameters["@img1sml"].Value = filUpload.FileName;` The DatedPosted works great, but not my file name. Thanks again

Comment: It seems this line is incorrect: `comm.Parameters.Add["@img1sml"].Value = filUpload.FileName;`. Thanks once more. I'm now "approving" past comments.

Comment: Hi Muhammad. Sorry to be a pest, but here is my current code: http://pastebin.com/SHpUHfsE. Using this, I get the error: `Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@img1sml' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.` Do I need to "Add" @img1sml to my parameter list? Thank you

Comment: Result! I used `comm.Parameters.Add("@img1sml", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text);
            comm.Parameters["@img1sml"].Value = filUpload.FileName;` and it now works. Many thanks again Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing file in the db too. This will guarantee data consistency.

Add column to the DB. Replace X with the suitable size if the image is less than 8000, or specify varbinary(MAX) if it is not.

```
alter table Entries
    add FileContent varbinary(X) not null
```

C# code:

```
byte[] fileContent = yourFileContent;
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = @"
        INSERT INTO Entries (Title, Description, FileContent)
        VALUES (@Title, @Description, @FileContent)
        ";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", descriptionTextBox.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", titleTextBox.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FileContent", fileContent);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Good shout. I'm normally a bit weary of adding file data straight into the database but will take a look at this. Thanks for such a prompt reply.